# Sort and set REST API data into a new list

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create a report table based from an API, but the API currently is not sorted as I wanted it to be and I'm not sure how to rearrange it. Here's an example of how the API that look like this :

```
[
    {
        "task": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Texturing",
        },
        "assign_to": {
            "id": 1,
            "official_name": "Roy Harper",
        },
        "duration": 3.0,
    },
    {
        "task": {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Lighting",
        },
        "assign_to": {
            "id": 3,
            "official_name": "Donna Troy",
        },
        "duration": 4.0,
    },
    {
            "task": {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Rendering",
            },
            "assign_to": {
                "id": 1,
                "official_name": "Roy Harper",
            },
            "duration": 7.0,
    },
    {
            "task": {
                "id": 11,
                "name": "Coloring",
            },
            "assign_to": {
                "id": 3,
                "official_name": "Donna Troy",
            },
            "duration": 5.0,
    },
{

]
```

What i trying to achieve now, is an API list that centralize on the `assign_to` field and also set the list so it only populate the same person once. here's how the desired output that I trying to achieve :

```
[
    {
        "assign_to": {
            "id": 1,
            "official_name": "Roy Harper",
        },
        "total_task"[
           "task":{
             "id": 4,
             "name": "Lighting",
           },
           "duration": 3.0,
           "task":{
             "id": 8,
             "name": "Rendering",
           },
           "duration": 7.0,
        ],
    },
    {
        "assign_to": {
            "id": 3,
            "official_name": "Donna Troy",
        },
        "total_task"[
           "task":{
             "id": 4,
             "name": "Lighting",
           },
           "duration": 4.0,
           "task": {
             "id": 11,
             "name": "Coloring",
           },
           "duration": 5.0,
        ],
    },
]
```

Below is my code :

Model.py :

```
class TaskOrder(models.Model):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    assign_to = models.ForeignKey(Employee, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='assign_to', null=True, blank=True)
    duration = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
```

serializer.py :

```
class ReportContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    assign_to = AssignToSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = WorkOrder
        fields = ('task', 'assign_to', 'duration')
        depth = 1
```

api.py :

```
class ReportContentAPI(APIView):
    def get(self, request, project_id, parent_id):
        all_taskorders = TaskOrder.objects.all().filter(content__project_id=project_id, content__parent_id=parent_id)
        report_content_serializer = ReportContentSerializer(all_taskorders, many=True)
        return Response(report_content_serializer.data)
```

Any help is much appreciated thank you very much.

Comment: Can you also add `Employee` model?